# Typescript defaultProps not checking type

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-props

I'm using TypeScript 3.0 and according to the documentation from https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-0.html

> Use `static defaultProps: Pick<Props, "name">;` as an explicit type
>   annotation instead, or do not add a type annotation as done in the
>   example above.

However if I write:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';

interface Props {
  counter: number;
}

export default class NumberCounter extends Component<Props> {
  static defaultProps = {
    counter: "i am not a number"
  };

  render() {

    return (
      <div>{this.props.counter}</div>
    );
  }
}
```

It compiles and works, apparently the prop's default value isn't typechecked. Nonetheless, when I try to use the component erroneously:

```
<NumberCounter 
  counter="still not a number"
/>
```

It shows an error, and typechecks correctly when it is used elsewhere. Is this a known bug with TypeScript?

Comment: See https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/issues/28515 .

Answer (score 0):

You should have a type assigned to `defaultProps` not only the component itself:

```
static defaultProps: Props = {
    counter: "i am not a number"
};
```

Comment: Does it work for you in TypeScript 3.0? The problem I'm getting by using this approach is if I only want to  assign default values to some of my props, TypeScript will throw an error requiring me to assign default values to all the properties defined in the `Props` interface.

Comment: In that case you can do `defaultProps: Partial<Props>` and make the counter in Props `counter?: string;`

Comment: Wouldn't work either. This issue is mentioned in the docs I linked: `The default-ed properties are inferred from the defaultProps property type. If an explicit type annotation is added, e.g. static defaultProps: Partial<Props>; the compiler will not be able to identify which properties have defaults (since the type of defaultProps include all properties of Props).`